# Lazy loading in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have 2 entities and I am joining them using **many to many** relation.

```
package com.app.mms.entity;

import ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "insurance_company")
public class InsuranceCompany{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "insurance_survey",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_insurance_company") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_survey_company") })
    private List<SurveyCompany> surveyCompany;

   // Getters, setters and constructor
}
```

and

```
package com.app.mms.entity;

import ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "survey_company")
public class SurveyCompany{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "insurance_survey",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_survey_company") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_insurance_company") })
    private List<InsuranceCompany> insuranceCompany;

       // Getters, setters and constructor
    }
```

and have 2 Jpa repositores:

```
package com.app.mms.dao;

import ...
@Repository
public interface InsuranceCompanyDao extends JpaRepository<InsuranceCompany, Long>{
}

package com.app.mms.dao;

import ...

@Repository
public interface SurveyCompanyDao extends JpaRepository<SurveyCompany, Long>{
}
```

and my **application.properties** contains:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./Database/mmsdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=mms
spring.datasource.password=mms
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

And Im trying to lazily retrieve entities but I get exception:

```
System.out.println("All Survey companies:");
System.out.println(surveyCompanyDao.findAll());

System.out.println("All Insurance companies:");
System.out.println(insuranceCompanyDao.findAll());

// I imagine, after calling findAll() the session is already closed, 
//and then I try to retrieve the insurance company for that survey company because of lazy, and I get exception.
System.out.println(insuranceCompanyDao.findAll().get(0).getSurveyCompany());
```

And the exception is :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.app.mms.entity.InsuranceCompany.surveyCompany, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:602) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:148) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:537) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at com.app.mms.MmsApplication.run(MmsApplication.java:63) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

How can I retreive the data lazily in **Spring boot**? I found some solutions in which they are initializing a **session** again (which spring boot by default provides in the Repository). I am not very sure whether that is the correct way to do it as I am very new to Spring boot. It would be great if someone can explain what is the correct way to lazily retrieve data in **spring boot**.

**Edit**:

My **main class**:

```
package com.app.mms;

import ...

@SpringBootApplication
public class MmsApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    InsuranceCompanyDao insuranceCompanyDao;

    @Autowired
    SurveyCompanyDao surveyCompanyDao;

   @Autowired
   InsuranceCompanyService service;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MmsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In command line runner...");

        System.out.println("All Survey companies:");
        System.out.println(surveyCompanyDao.findAll());

        System.out.println("All Insurance companies:");
        System.out.println(insuranceCompanyDao.findAll());

     InsuranceCompany ic = insuranceCompanyDao.findAll().get(0);            
        System.out.println(service.getSurveyCompany(ic));

    }
}
```

My Service class:

```
import ...

@Service
public class InsuranceCompanyService {
@Autowired
InsuranceCompanyDao insuranceCompanyDao;

 @Transactional 
 public List<SurveyCompany> getSurveyCompany(InsuranceCompany insuranceCompany){ 
 List<SurveyCompany> surveyCompanies = insuranceCompany.getSurveyCompany(); 
return surveyCompanies; 
} 
}
```

Comment: Put your code inside a transaction, so that the session is not closed. Also, fix your mapping: it's incorrect. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: So I need to make a service in between JpaRepository and accessing the data? so I can wrap my service methods in transaction using Transactional, correct? I will correct the mapping, thanks.

Comment: Or make whatever method you're currently executing transactional (i.e. the method wrapping all these System.out.println statements).

Comment: @Transactional
    public void printSurvey(){
        System.out.println(insuranceCompanyDao.findAll().get(0).getSurveyCompany());
    }
I tried this, but it still throws the same error.

Comment: Is this method located in a Spring bean and called from another spring bean (and not from another method of the same class)? Post all the relevant code.

Comment: I created this method in the main class, and called it inside the run method.

Comment: Post all the relevant code.

Comment: I have posted my main class.

Comment: So you did call the transactional method from another method of the same class. That can't work. The method has to be called from the outside, so that the transactional proxy intercepts the method. Making the run() method itself transactional should work.

Comment: Yeah it works! Thanks for the clarification. It really helps a lot :) You can post it as answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @JBNizet I created a service and a method inside that to load that lazy object, and mark that method as Transactional. and remove the transactional annotation from the run method. and I am again getting the exception. I dont get how. becuase both are different class now, and method also marked as transactional.

Comment: My service method is:
    @Transactional
    public List<SurveyCompany> getSurveyCompany(InsuranceCompany insuranceCompany){
        List<SurveyCompany> surveyCompanies = insuranceCompany.getSurveyCompany();
        return surveyCompanies;
    }

Comment: I guess the problem is my main class is not a bean, that's why i can't call that method there?

Comment: No. The problem is that you're once again trying to load the lazy association *outside* of the transaction. Do *all* of your work with entities *inside* a transaction.

Comment: So does it mean that, the method where im calling the method that loads the data lazily, should use the transactional annotation, not the method definition?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If a method loads data lazily and it's not transactional, then the session is closed, so the data cannot be loaded. It's as simple as that. As soon as a transaction ends, all the entities that have been loaded during that tranasction become detached, and you can't load anything lazily out of them anymore.

Comment: I have edited my code and added the service class. That's what i did tried. So even though i marked my service method as transactional and i retreive the lazy object inside that, still i need to mark my run method transactional? because im calling service method in run(). Sorry for bad editing, Im using phone.

Comment: Here' what happens in your code. Your run() method is not transactional. Your DAO methods are. So calling findAll() starts a transaction, gets the list, returns it, and ends the transaction. At that point, all the entities in the returned list are detached. Trying to lazy-load anything from them will fail. Restarting a new transaction won't help: once they're detached, they're detached. Then you're calling another transactional service (getSurveyCompany, which should really be named getSurveyCompanies).

Comment: This service doesn't do anything useful. It gets the survey companies out of the detached insuranceCompany passed as argument. That doesn't even lazy-load anything. If it did, it would fail anyway. What will try to lazy-load the elemets of the list is the call to System.out.println(), which needs to print the list, and thus to iterate over its elements, and thus to load the elements from the database. But that will fail since the list is detached from the moment your DAO.findAll() method returned. Again: do **all** the work with your entities inside **a** transaction.